# Types of values in Elm

Tags: functional-programming, elm

In the [documentation](http://elm-lang.org/guide/core-language#values) of elm, `values` are mentioned. Clearly strings, integers and floats are values in Elm. I guess also booleans True and False are values in elm.

Are these the only types of basic values or are there any others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic types that can be represented with [literals](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#literals) include:

- `Int`
- `Float`
- `Bool`
- `Char`
- `String`